# How to iterate inside respond_to according to rails variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a way to display multiple forms in a table when a new Cars is saved.

I don't know how to iterate with Cars Options in order to pass Cars & Options parameters to Values form inside Cars create.js.erb

**cars.rb**

```
def create
 ...
 if @car.save
  @fleet.options.each do |option|
   new_value = Value.new(car_id: @car.id, option_id: option.id)
   new_value.save
  @options_values << [option.id, new_value.id]
 end
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to edit_fleet_path(@fleet) }
  format.js
 end
...
end
```

I try, each time a car is created, to display a new column in a table and to display for each existing option (which are table's rows), displaying the corresponding value form.

**create.js.erb**

```
<% if @car.errors.any? %>
 $("#newCarForm").html("<%= j render 'cars/form', fleet: @fleet, car: @car %>"); // => it's ok
<% else %>
 $("#newCarForm").before("<td></td>"); // => it's ok
 $("#carTitleRow th:last-child").after("<th><%= @car.title %></td>"); // => it's ok
 $("#carUrlRow td:last-child").after("<td><%= @car.url %></td>"); // => it's ok

 // MY PROBLEM IS BELOW
 var newcell = $("<td>Hello</td>") 
 $("*[id^='optionRow-']").append(newcell);

<% end %>
```

Each `#optionRow-XXXX`XXXX is the corresponding option's id.
I have same ids in @options_values array

I'd like to be able to iterate in order to, for each `#optionRow-XXXX`, looking for right option and value, pass them in params to 'values/form' and finally have something like that:

```
var newcell = $("<td><%= j render 'values/form', option: @option, value: @value %></td>")
```

During my tests I had these problems:

- I know how to get optionRow id with jQuery and get option.id with rails but I know I can't pass js var to rails.
- I tried to use a `@option_values.each` without success
- I tried to use a js while loop without success

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass those variables with the locals object I think. So instead of

```
$("<td><%= j render 'values/form', option: @option, value: @value %>
```

do

```
$("<td><%= j render 'values/form', locals: {option: @option, value: @value} %></td>")
```